# When image clicked opacity will be down

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am making a collection update app and I would like the user to be able to click on the card that he have ( it will be an image in a library of all the card in the collection ), and when he have it ( so when he click on it ) the opacity of this image will go down by half until he decide to reclick on it ( let’s imagine if he lost it or sell it and don’t have it anymore) …

Sadly after one week of checking around internet, and trying to find a solution by learning new things… my brain is stuck…

I would like to know if there was maybe an if statement in swift which could only act on the opacity ?

Sorry if that may seems really easy and comon sense for you !

Comment: Hello. You have to keep in a variable if the image is selected or not, and adapte the opacity based on this flag

Answer (score 1):

There are inline ifs:

Boolean variable

```
@State private var clicked = false
```

View:

```
Image(...)
   .opacity(clicked ? 1.0 : 0.5)
```